descargar un archivo usando window.location.assign de javascript y direccionar la descarga a la carpeta documentos de windows
Al descargar un archivo, deseo que la descarga se realice en la carpeta documentos de windows y ya no en la carpeta descargas, esta redireccion quiero hacerlo usando javascript, es factible?
        $.ajax({
            url: PROYECTOCGR.resolveClientURL('~/Common.aspx/setKeyLaserFiche'),
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'filtro': parFiltro
            }),
            async:false,
            success: function (result) {
                var data = result.d;
                if (data.Success) {
                    var url = PROYECTOCGR.resolveClientURL("~/Areas/Documentos/DownloadHandler.ashx?");
                    url = url + "CodOpe=LASERFICHE&IdNoti=" + idNoti + "&IdExp=" + idExp + "&IdFase=" + idFase + "&IdMedi=" + idMedi + "&Usr=" + data.RecordsAux;
                    window.location.assign(url);
                }
                else {
                    PROYECTOCGR.MostrarMensaje(data.Msg, 'Info');
                    PROYECTOCGR.HideProgress();
                }
            }
        });


No es posible a menos que el usuario desee guardarlo en documentos. JavaScript por sí mismo, en el navegador, no puede controlar el ordenador del usuario, fuera de la página web actual, bajo ninguna circunstancia. Esto incluye elegir dónde se puede guardar un documento, lo cual es manejado totalmente por el usuario, no el código.

El usuario es el rey y no puedes decidir por él. Será él, con sus configuraciones y acciones, el que decida a dónde irá a parar el archivo que descarga.
